# warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to ‘char*’ when i add a formal parameter in the function def but with no actual parameter

Tags: c++

The code below doesnt throw any warnings while i compile

```
 #include <iostream>

 void GetHMACCode(unsigned char* buffer,long bufferLength,unsigned char** pResult,unsigned int &nResultLen){}

 unsigned char *pCRCBufferptr ;

 main() {
 unsigned char *pHMAC  = NULL;
 int ncrcDataLength;
 unsigned int nHMACLen = 0;
 GetHMACCode(pCRCBufferptr,ncrcDataLength,&pHMAC,nHMACLen);

 }
```

But When i add an extra argument in the function (not in the function call), I get the below warning

```
myFile.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
myFile.cpp:11: warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to ‘char*’
```

Added extra arguement in the function

```
 #include <iostream>

 void GetHMACCode(unsigned char* buffer,long bufferLength,unsigned char** pResult,unsigned int &nResultLen,char *extra_arg = "11111111111111111111"){}

 unsigned char *pCRCBufferptr ;

 main() {
 unsigned char *pHMAC  = NULL;
 int ncrcDataLength;
 unsigned int nHMACLen = 0;
 GetHMACCode(pCRCBufferptr,ncrcDataLength,&pHMAC,nHMACLen);

 }
```

I am confused why this warnign is being thrown

Thanks
Tejas

Comment: @Holt: Instead of ignoring the warning, the OP would be better understanding that in C++ a string literal can only be assigned to `const char*` and `char*` is only for backwards compatibility with C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding `const` solves your problem:

```
void GetHMACCode(unsigned char* buffer,
                 long bufferLength,
                 unsigned char** pResult,
                 unsigned int &nResultLen,
                 const char *extra_arg = "11111111111111111111") // const added here
{}
```

Answer (score 2):

The warning is about converting the string literal to a non-const char* (`char* extra_arg = "..."`).

Changing the definition of your function to the following should make the warning go away:

```
void GetHMACCode(unsigned char* buffer,long bufferLength,unsigned char** pResult,unsigned int &nResultLen, const char *extra_arg = "11111111111111111111"){}
```

Comment: so after this change my code is throwing run time error

Comment: undefined reference to `GetHMACCode(unsigned char*, long, unsigned char**, unsigned int&, char const*)' when i call this function without last argument   GetHMACCode(pCRCBufferptr, ncrcDataLength, &pHMAC, nHMACLen);

Comment: @user2256825 Have you changed both the declaration in your header and the definition in you implementation file?

Comment: The definition and declaration are both  actually in the header file , Changed both now, and is  working fine

Comment: Dont forgot to accept an answer if it solved your problem.